# Gson stackoverflow on toJson .... CLUELESS

Tags: android, json, cycle

I'm getting this error but it makes no sense...

This is the code for saving the gson:

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(new Pais("a",null));
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(c.getApplicationInfo().dataDir+File.separatorChar+"datos.json");
            writer.write(json);
            writer.close();
            System.out.println(json);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is Pais class:

```
public class Pais  {
    public String nombre;
    public Drawable bandera;

    public Pais(String n,Drawable b){
        this.nombre=n;
        this.bandera=b;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }


    public Drawable getBandera() {
    return bandera;
}
public void setBandera(Drawable bandera) {
    this.bandera = bandera;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other){
    return (((Pais)other).nombre.equals(this.nombre));
}   
  }
```

I don't understand the error since it has no cycle or anything... do I neen an annotation on the class?

Thank you!
José.

EDIT: My stacktrace:

```
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     ... 11 more
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161): Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
04-02 13:03:31.504: E/AndroidRuntime(2161):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gso
```

Comment: how do you expect the `drawable` to be serialized? also, post your stacktrace.

Comment: `it has no cycle` ???

Comment: I am thinking the null drawable is the cause of your problem?

Comment: it's not the null drawable... it throws the same if I put a valid drawable..

Comment: Why do you want to save the drawable itself in the model, making it unecessary heavyweight, why dont you save the drawable id? Or if this is dynamic just set a file link? I don't thinks its easy or safe to serialze a drawable

Comment: anyways... is that the problem thats causing the stackoverflow?

Comment: not the problem, just changed the drawable to its id and still getting the stackoverflow...